# Old interface and default keywords

Tags: dart

I came across the following in a 2 years old dart code

```
interface BindingConverter default IdentityBindingConverter {
  BindingConverter();

  Object convertFromModel(Object value);
  Object convertToModel(Object value);
}

class IdentityBindingConverter implements BindingConverter {
  Object convertFromModel(Object value) => value;
  Object convertToModel(Object value) => value;
}
```

i know that the interface keyword is eliminated and instead abstract should be used, but what is the default keyword? is it with or extends or something else, default implementation maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "default implementation class" was a way to forward constructors from an interface to an implementation class' constructors.

Now that there are no interfaces, all classes can forward constructors to any of their subclasses.
You forward each constructor individually, using the `factory Foo.bar(baz, qux) = SubFoo.bar;` syntax.

```dart
abstract class BindingConverter {
  // Forwards the arguments to IndentityBindingConverter's unnamed constructor.
  factory BindingConverter() = IdentityBindingConverter;   
  Object convertFromModel(Object value);
  Object convertToModel(Object value);
}
class IdentityBindingConverter implements BindingConverter {
  Object convertFromModel(Object value) => value;
  Object convertToModel(Object value) => value;
}
```